# JQUERY Fade out, not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My generated Html markup is

```
<ul class="list">
   <li class="tile" id="row-5">

   </li>
</ul>
```

My AJAX post is

```
$.post("/Faq/Delete", { "id": recordToDelete},
                            function (data) {
                                var row = "row-" + data;
                                $(row).fadeOut('slow');
                            });
```

But when i call `$(row).fadeOut('slow');`the selected line is not removed.
What am i doing wrong here?

Assume the recordToDelete value equals 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to prefix `#` to use [ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
var row = "row-" + data;
$('#' + row).fadeOut('slow');
//^^^ Add #
```

OR

```
var row = "#row-" + data;
//^^^ Add #
$(row).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: Why not just go `var row = "#row-" + data;`?

Comment: @JamesMichaelLucas, Even that will work, but showing `#` in a random string variable bears no significance, thus used `$('#' + row)` where it matters